# How to open the Gallery view Under My app

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I am working on an App which is selecting a single picture at a time from the gallery. Right Now I have used the intent to open the gallery. But I do not want to use this. This is just because of the Use Case which is as below :

> If the user Selects the Picture which is not in Portrait then my app should show him dialog to warn him that he is selecting the wrong Photo. Only Portrait photos are allowed.

So for this, I think If I would open the gallery by intent I can not achieve this, So I moved to another Idea , to bring all the photos from the gallery into the app. For this I tried using the Universal image loader, But Unfortunately it is slow and not looking good.

So is there any way to open the device Gallery into the app directly  so please guide me share me the code or any link. thanks

Comment: `If I would open the gallery by intent I can not achieve this,`. In onActivityResult you can check if it is in portrait mode and display a Toast.

Comment: how can I check the orientation ?

Comment: as the orientation of tabs and other devices are different.

Comment: If you have the path to a jpg file read orientation from exif info. If you have a content uri you can query the media store for it.

Comment: can you please please please give me example code